# appendChild doesn't append the same element twice

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a `valuesArray` and a `transcribedPoems` arrays. If a key is present in both of them, I want to add an `option` to my `select` element in both the `Transcribed` and the `All` subgroups. If not, then I want the option to be available only in the `All` subrgoup. This is my code:

```
let valuesArray = [   
    ["1", "a manuscript"], ["2", "another one"]
]

const transcribedPoems =['2']

let optGroupTranscribed = document.createElement("optgroup");
optGroupTranscribed.setAttribute("label", "Transcribed")

let optGroupAll = document.createElement("optgroup");
optGroupAll.setAttribute("label", "All")

let select = document.createElement("select");

valuesArray.forEach(function(element) {
        
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = element[0];
        option.text = element[1];
        
        if (transcribedPoems.includes(element[0])) {

            optGroupTranscribed.appendChild(option);
            optGroupAll.appendChild(option);
            
        }  else {
        
            optGroupAll.appendChild(option);
        }
        
    });

select.appendChild(optGroupTranscribed);
select.appendChild(optGroupAll);
    
document.getElementById("manifests").appendChild(select);
```

The above code doesn't append anything to `optGroupTranscribed` though. I noticed that if I take the `optGroupAll.appendChild(option);` out from the condition, then I do have the transcribed poems in the `transcribed` subgroup (and not in the `All` one). I want the transcribed poems to also be in the `All` subgroup though. What am I missing?

What I get:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Transcribed">
    <option value="2">another one</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="All">    
    <option value="1">a manuscript</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Expected result:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Transcribed">
    <option value="2">another one</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="All">    
    <option value="1">a manuscript</option>
    <option value="2">another one</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo What do you mean? I realised I forgot the last bit of code, I've added it now. My code does work, it just doesn't append to `transcribed` when I add two `appendChild` in my `if`. If I only put one, then it works as expected.

Comment: Finally, I see that you have come to understand that the method `appendChild`, does not do element cloning... that being said, recognize that it is still easier to use a `new Option()` , like I showed it to you in my answer here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do that this way...

doc :
[`optionElement = new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

```js
const
  newElm = (tag, props={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props)
, transcribedPoems = ['2']
, valuesArray =
    [ ['1', 'a manuscript']
    , ['2', 'another one' ]
    ]
, mySelect = document
      .querySelector('#manifests')
      .appendChild( newElm('select',{name:'select',id:'objectAssign'})) 
  ;
let optGroupTranscribed = mySelect.appendChild(newElm('optgroup',{label:'Transcribed'}))
  , optGroupAll         = mySelect.appendChild(newElm('optgroup',{label:'All'}))
  , doSelect            = true
  ;
valuesArray.forEach(([val,lib]) => 
  {
  if ( transcribedPoems.includes(val))
    {
    optGroupTranscribed.appendChild( new Option(lib,val,doSelect,doSelect) )
    doSelect = false
    }
  optGroupAll.appendChild( new Option(lib,val) )
  })
```

```html
<div id="manifests"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this 'better' / more performant than `cloneNode()`?

Comment: @HBMCS yes, it's really better, the use of cloning implies a parsing of the elements and properties, and sub lements... before repeating them, which necessarily less efficient than their "creation"  live

Comment: @HBMCS  added the option default selected element

Comment: @HBMCS changed my answer by adding element properties

Comment: @HBMCS works the same for `optgroup` elements ;)

Comment: Does it work with classes too? I added `class` and it doesn't seem to like it. `name:'select',id:'object-select',class:"form-select form-select-lg mb-3"`

Comment: I'm adding the classes with `select.classList.add()` later in the script.

Comment: @HBMCS  use `className` as propertie   : `newElm('xxx',{className:'xx yy zz'})`

Comment: Excellent, I didn't think of trying with `className`.

Answer (score 4):

There's an interesting subtlety here. When you use `createElement`, it creates an instance of HTMLElement (for the subclass `option`). When you `appendChild` that element to another element, it is placed in that element's DOM tree.

If you go to place that same element in another element's DOM tree, it would make it so that the overall tree (the one that would contain both `optGroupTranscribed` and `optGroupAll`) NOT a tree, since there would be one child `option` shared by both elements.

Instead, you can call `option.cloneNode()` to make a copy of the element. So, try changing it to:

```js
optGroupTranscribed.appendChild(option.cloneNode());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a step in the right direction. Now, with cloneNode() 1. I do get the option in `All` too, although it's without label, so it's showing as an empty option (although the key is correct). 2. when I select it from the 'all' subgroup, I get 'redirected' to the same option in the 'transcribed' option group.

Comment: PS: I've solved the missing text by adding the `deep` option to cloneNode().

Answer (score 3):

In *one* iteration of the `forEach` loop, you only create *one* `option` element, and so you cannot expect to have two as a result.

The second call to  `appendChild` actually *moves* the `option` there, taking it out of the first option group.

You can call `option.cloneNode(true)` to get around this.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful. Nevertheless, it's not quite right yet. See my comment to the other answer.

Comment: Yes, as you saw from my comment, I did get the `deep` option :). Still, is there a way to retain the 'select' class to the `option` actually selected, instead of it going to the first occurrence of that `option` when the second one is selected?

Comment: If you have follow up questions, consider asking a new question.